# Using non-const variable inside constexpr?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constexpr

Consequently to a previous question about const/non-const with ternary operator, is the following `test` function ok regarding to the C++11 standard :

```
template<bool UseConst> class MyClass
{
    public:
        constexpr bool test()
        {
             return (UseConst) ? (_constvar) : (_var);
        }

    protected:
        int _var;
        static const int _constvar;
}
```

The whole problem, is that `_constvar` is const, and `_var` is non-const. I would have to access these 2 data depending on the template parameter through the same function, and I would like to have a compile-time function when I use const.

Do the `test()` function satisfy my requirements ?

Comment: Why not simply specialize on `UseConst` and go from there?

Comment: Specialize what ? The class or the function ? For the class, I have a large set of functions and it would be far more easier and concise to retrieve the const or the non-const through a single function like here. To specialize the function, I do not see how to do that...

Comment: @Vincent : Non-template member functions inside of class templates are actually just function templates and can be specialized as such without specializing the entire class. See e.g. the code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12598245/636019).

Comment: Shouldn't `test()` return an `int`? And what is the problem in making this test function `constexpr`? It compiles for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use SFINAE in order to "specialize" your `test` function.  In other words, you could do something like the following:

```
template<bool true_false>
struct true_type
{
    static char value;
};

template<>
struct true_type<false>
{
    static char value[2];
};

template<bool UseConst> class MyClass
{
    private:
        constexpr int pre_test(const char arg) { return _constvar; }
        int pre_test(char (&)[2]) const { return _var; }

    public:
        constexpr int test()
        {
             return pre_test(true_type<UseConst>::value);
        }

    protected:
        int _var;
        static const int _constvar;
};
```

Now, when you call `MyClass::test`, if `UseConst` is `false`, `test` will degrade to a run-time function, but when `UseConst` is `true`, you will get a compile-time function.